# More efficient creation of objects and object arrays in a recursive function? C++

Tags: c++, arrays, object

I'm currently writing a chess engine, and recently profiled it. I was pretty surprised to see that the second most expensive operation (aside from the search function itself) is the creation of my move generation object, barely below my evaluation function. I'm relatively new to programming, so there's more than likely a much better way of doing what I'm doing currently.

As it stands, the move generation object is initialized right before the moves loop in the search function, and the bitboards are copied over from my bitboard object(which costs nothing compared to the const of creating the object itself).

Here's the header file for the moveGeneration object, it contains an array of move objects(which the creation of is pretty expensive as well) I've also left out the functions for ease of viewing, I can post them if need be though.

```
class MoveGen
{
public:
MoveGen();

//array of move objects 
Move moveAr[256];

bool isWhite;
//number of moves generated this node
int moveCount;

//bitboards
    U64 FullTiles;
    U64 EmptyTiles;
    U64 BBWhitePieces;
    U64 BBWhitePawns;
    U64 BBWhiteRooks;
    U64 BBWhiteKnights;
    U64 BBWhiteBishops;
    U64 BBWhiteQueens;
    U64 BBWhiteKing;
    U64 BBBlackPieces;
    U64 BBBlackPawns;
    U64 BBBlackRooks;
    U64 BBBlackKnights;
    U64 BBBlackBishops;
    U64 BBBlackQueens;
    U64 BBBlackKing;
};
```

For completeness, here's the the Move object info:

```
class Move
{
public:
Move();

U8 from;
U8 to;
char piece;
char captured;
int score;
U8 flag;
bool tried;
};

Move::Move(){
     tried = false;
}
```

Is there anything glaringly obvious that I could do to speed up the creation of the move generation object? I'm open to a complete re-work of anything, as this is a huge drain on the speed of my program.

I've thought about removing the local bitboards inside the MoveGen class and just passing a const & of the bitboards object to the MoveGen functions. Although I think the main slowdown is coming from the creation of the object array. MoveGen::MoveGen has 23.18% inclusive samples in my profiling, and Move::Move has 11.31%, both very high compared to everything but the search itself.

I apologize if this is too general a question and I'll delete it if that's the case. Any advice on a more efficient way to do this would be much appreciated though!

Comment: you could - remove the constructor for class `Move` and instead in the constructor for class `MoveGen` simply `memset` the `moveAr` array to zeros.  RIght now it might be calling the `Move` constructor 256 times.  (BTW, you remembered to profile an optimized build not a debug build, right?)

Comment: memset the array of objects inside the GenMoves()? Would that set the object variables to zero's? The only one that matters is the false flag at the moment, to point to a non real move (which I should probably be using pointers for). Yeah it's profiling on the x64 release version.

Comment: For any chess game, presumably you would only need at most two "move generation" objects.   If the creation is a performance bottleneck, then either your program isn't doing much else or you're creating lots of objects.   The questions would then be why are you creating/copying lots of objects? and can you avoid that?

Comment: another option especially if the `Move` objects in `moveAr` are used in a structured way, e.g., in a stack mode - remove `Move::tried` and keep track of that separately - then `Move` need no constructor at all.

Comment: Do you need to these objects to be new or be same as on previous recursion level? If same, then you can try to pass them as reference to next level of recursion to avoid creation of new copy of object.

Comment: @MaxC - yeah, just zero the whole array, zeroing every `Move` in the array.

Comment: P.S. you didn't show `MoveGen::MoveGen()` - I assume it is trivial or is otherwise known not to contribute to the time?

Comment: Right now I'm creating them because the moves are stored in them, do you think it'd it be faster to create a vector inside the search and have the generate moves function return a vector of move objects?

Comment: MoveGen::MoveGen() is empty at the moment. The objects need to be different at each level because currently they hold the array of moves, and some other data like bitboards accurate to that turn.

Comment: @MaxC - no, not a vector (although you can try it and time it).  No, just move "Tried" out of the Move especially since "trying" the move is something MoveGen is responsible for, not a Move, which is just trying to record data about a move.

Comment: Would the memset look like memset(moveAr, 0, sizet(Move))? The tried is also used to detect if the move is real or not, in the case of transposition table returning an entry but not move.

Comment: Might be worth the 1 time hit to dynamically allocate the array, and then just clear them as needed.

Comment: The memset() method is looking really promising. I'm just confused as to what to set the last value to. Should it be the number of bytes in a move? The max number of moves? M4rc  As in a pointer to an array of objecst?

Comment: `memset` will be really fast if you are setting too few bytes.  :-)  The bytes is the total number of bytes in `moveAr`, which is simply `sizeof(moveAr)`.

Comment: Yeah, the too few bytes was definitely the problem Haha. memset(&moveAr, 0, sizeof(moveAr)); was about 30% slower than the way I've been doing it :(. Would a pointer to an array be possibly faster so i'm only constructing the move objects that i need to?

Comment: Another option is to keep track of how many moves you have generated and not clear the rest. Saves you from filling the 200 moves hardly ever used.

Comment: The tracking is already done in a sense, how would I only clear the first x moves like that? Currently with the variable Move moveAr[256] it creates all of the on MoveGen object creation

Comment: How do you construct MoveGens?  Are they in a vector, a C array, a list, what?  Also, are your constructors defined `inline` or in a .cpp file?

Comment: They are just individual objects that are constructed inside the search right before the move loop. They're MoveGen::MoveGen() inside the .cpp file, they're MoveGen(); inside the header

Comment: Try defining the constructors inline in the header file instead and see if that makes any difference.  Also, if a default constructor does nothing, better to remove it and let the compiler auto-generate it.  Can you also post your complete build command line(s)?

Comment: As far as I know I don't have any build command lines, whatever visual studio is defaulting to I guess? I'm guessing I should though? I'll try to inline both constructors of move and MoveGen, Thanks!

Comment: Stupid question, but you are building in Release right?

Comment: Yup! it's a x64 release build i'm profiling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it contains an array of move objects(which the creation of is pretty expensive as well)

Based on that alone it's in your best interest to allocate however many `MoveGen` objects you need up front before entering the recursive function. This means you have two options, allocate from the heap, or in the stack before the function call. Allocating up front and passing pointers around is way faster than creating big objects repeatedly in a loop.

As several commenters have noted, the high percentage is because you're repeatedly constructing `MoveGen` objects, requiring the construction of 256 `Move` objects each time, and your `Move` objects are expensive. This is because every type with a non-trivial constructor(basically, user-defined) must be constructed in place after being allocated. Fields in a class are allocated when the containing class is allocated, in each recursive call in your case. If you don't do this yourself for non-trivial types the compiler will do it for you to ensure your objects are correctly initialized, which is what's happening in your code.

In general, you always want to pre-allocate as much as possible, especially in the case of big and/or expensive objects.

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion from John Zwinck of inlining the constructor for Move as well as removing the constructor for MoveGen did the trick. While it was a moderate increase in performance, the two constructors that previously showed as very intensive in profiling no longer do. Thanks!